# How do you start an on-line community?

Tags: community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start and encourage an online community?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17532/how-to-start-and-encourage-an-online-community)

How do you start an on-line community QA site similar to stackoverflow?

Comment: You start by writing software that might foster it? After that, seek patient investors.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you start an on-line community
>   QA site similar to stackoverflow?

This question was answered recently by Joel Spolsky:

> We learned a long time ago that the
>   only way to get questions answered
>   promptly is to have a critical mass of
>   knowledgeable users, so we have an
>   onerous process called Area 51 where
>   sites are proposed, discussed, and
>   voted on. If a proposed site doesn’t
>   have critical mass, we just won’t
>   create it.

[Stack Overflow 2010 Recap](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2011/01/24.html)

If you're interested in starting up a similar venture, you'll find plenty of good advice and ideas at [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and at [Joel's blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have web development skills you could try building your own.  But for a pre-built script check out some of the clones mentioned here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones